# Could not cast value of type 'Swift._ContiguousArrayStorage crash

Tags: ios, swift3

I am trying to set data from model class to table view. But it is crashing and giving me this error "Could not cast value of type `'Swift._ContiguousArrayStorage<AppName.Events>' (0x7feb2444e0b8)` to `'AppName.Events' (0x105bcd0d0)`". Here is my Code

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if tableView.tag == 201
    {
        // On this line it's crashing
        let item = selectedDateEventArr.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Events

        if item.eventType == "LEAVE" || item.eventType == "BIRTHDAY"{
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellBdayId", for: indexPath) as! MainPageBDayTableViewCell

            cell.nameLbl.text = item.title
            cell.eventtypeLbl.text = item.description
           //                cell.imageView?.image = 
            return cell
        }
        else
        {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! MainPageCalTableViewCell
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            cell.statusBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(statusBtnClicked(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
            return cell
        }

    }
 }
```

selectedDateEventArr is mutableArray in which i am adding the object of Events class after matching the current date.

```
   var selectedDateEventArr = NSMutableArray()
   let dt = Date()
    var dt1 = ConstantFile.dateToStringTemp(date: dt)
    for item in eventsArr {
        if (item.date == dt1){
            selectedDateEventArr.add(item.events!)
        }
    }
```

**Model Class**

```
 class Events: Mappable {
   var date: String?
   var eventId: Int?
   var description: String?
   var eventStatus: String?
   var eventType: String?
   var imageUrl: String?
   var isOwn: Bool?
   var title: String?

   required init?(map: Map){

   }

func mapping(map: Map) {
    date <- map["date"]
    eventId <- map["eventId"]
    description <- map["description"]
    eventStatus <- map["eventStatus"]
    eventType <- map["eventType"]
    imageUrl <- map["imageUrl"]
    isOwn <- map["isOwn"]
    title <- map["title"]
   }
 }
```

Comment: Do not use `NSMutable....` Foundation collection types in Swift at all. Declare your array `var selectedDateEventArr = [Events]()`. By the way, the plural form `Events` for – actually –  a single event is a bit confusing.

Comment: @vadian If i make selectedDateEventArr as selectedDateEventArr = [Events]() then how i can  get each Event object in cellForRowAt. Like in this line, i want to get each object from mutablearray let item = selectedDateEventArr.object(at: indexPath.row) as! Events.

Comment: It's much less code: `let item = selectedDateEventArr[indexPath.row]` (no type cast) and instead of `add` use `append`

Comment: I think i am working in pressure Lolzz.  thanks..:)

Comment: @vadian: "Not at all" -> "Not unless you have a good reason and could explain why if it was an interview question".